# VSCode search results doesn't show all instances

Tags: apex, vs-code, search

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with my search panel in VSCode when searching in a branch from BitBucket. When I try to look for a specific search term, it doesn't find ALL instances of that term (I know for sure it's missing). For example, when I search for `Send_to_a_delivery_company__c`, it finds me all profiles using it, and all **open editors** that have that instance

[image: search results no open editor]

When I open some file that has this instance, it´s being added to the list
[image: editor with opened class]

I tried using all kinds of glob includes, and it actually finds all the results when I try `*.cls`
[image: search results with *.cls]

But when I try the directory, for example, it doesn't find any results...

[image: search results - nothing found with directory glob include]

I watched [this amazing video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uc4I4ByUe0A) to see what can be done, and I tried the following:

1. Using glob include - as described above, only `*.cls` worked.
2. disabled `use exclude settings and ignore files` - The results remained the same.
3. Settings > Search Ignore - disabled. Remained the same.
4. Settings > Search Exclude - removed the default settings. Remained the same... I reset the setting to the default after that.

I will mention that this problem is ONLY for Bitbucket branches (all of them - master or new branches). I have colleagues who are using the same bitbucket workspace and it's working fine for them.

Answer (score 1):

Your directory search is currently `./classes`, which is terminal. It would only ever find that folder itself, not any files inside it. You want instead `*/classes/*`, which does not require the directory to be the terminus.

Comment: `./classes/*` doesn't match `force-app/main/default/classes`. `.` always refers to the root folder.

Comment: I was assuming he had verified that part of it, my mistake.

Comment: This was just an example of how I tried to narrow the search to "force" it to find the right instances, but it didn't. My end goal is to have all search results show up on the most basic search option, not to have to include directory or file type every time I search.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue at last... Apparently, I cloned the project in the wrong way... Instead of using the "Clone" button (and copying the repository with the .git suffix), I copied the URL from the repository which did actually clone but the structure was somehow corrupted.